# Pydantic way of having user defined object

Tags: python, pydantic

I am new to Pydantic and I am not sure what am I doing wrong here. I have defined my class and it inherits from BaseModel.

```
class EffectiveCoverage(BaseModel):
    start_date: str
    end_date: str
    env_path: Optional[str] = ""
    supply: Any = None
    effective_coverage: pd.DataFrame = None
    relative_coverage: Dict = dict()
    class_obj: SomeClass = None
```

It works and I can create an object for the same class but when I try to access the supply or class_obj it throws an AttributeError
`AttributeError: 'EffectiveCoverage' object has no attribute 'class_obj'`

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you share how you instantiated the object and tried accessing the attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can't easily be reproduced. Your example is incomplete, but after adding some required extra material (including a `Config` because there's no validator for `pd.DataFrame` or `SomeClass`):

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Optional, Any, Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel


class SomeClass:
    pass


class EffectiveCoverage(BaseModel):
    start_date: str
    end_date: str
    env_path: Optional[str] = ""
    supply: Any = None
    effective_coverage: pd.DataFrame = None
    relative_coverage: Dict = dict()
    class_obj: SomeClass = None

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True


ec = EffectiveCoverage(start_date='', end_date='')
print(ec.class_obj)
```

This code runs just fine, so your issue is likely with some of the code you're not sharing. This prints `None`.

Comment: Sorry about the incomplete code. I think I just missed the `arbitrary_types_allowed = True` part. It works now! Thanks a lot for the help :D